# How can I use Ionic 3 to get the content of a text file as a string?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried this:

```
this.item = this.params.get('filename');
console.log("[INFO] Opening File: >" + this.item + "<");
this.textboxContent = this.file.readAsText(this.file.dataDirectory, this.item);
console.log("[INFO] Content of textboxContent: >" + this.textboxContent + "<");
```

But i get in logcat:

> [INFO:CONSOLE(56865)] "[INFO] Content of textboxContent: >[object
>   Promise]<"

this.item is:

> [INFO:CONSOLE(56863)] "[INFO] Opening File: >SomeFile.txt<"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because readAsText returns a promise. You should do this instead

```
this.file.readAsText(this.file.dataDirectory, this.item).then((content)=>  
{
  this.textboxContent = content;
})
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please accept this answer? Thanks.

Comment: @MrFlyingToasterman Glad to hear that you solved the issue! Please mark this answer as the accepted answer so we can close the issue :)

Comment: I'm sorry I was still in a meeting and had a lunch break. Of course :)